# Farsi Layout in run-time and change gravity

Tags: android, layout, persian

I developed an application multi language English and Persian. English Layout works fine and exactly the same with preview in my IDE (Android studio).
But , Persian (Farsi) layouts have problem in run-time and doesn't looks like preview that i prepared in IDE. i run application in Nexus S5-Samsung Galaxy S6.
does anyone have an idea ??
[[image: This is English layout in IDE preview][image: This is Farsi layout (layout-ar)]
[image: This is what Farsi layout looks like in mobile device looks like its goes wrong]
[image]
this farsi layout code (layout-ar)

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:id="@+id/op_successfulLayout"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_border_op_seccessful">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:id="@+id/trx_result_tv" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/trx__result_img"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:src="@drawable/green_tick"/>

            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/op_successfulLayout"
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/headerReceiptLayout">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/mabna_company_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/company_name_label"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/mabna_number_txt"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/mabna_number_tv" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/shaparak_img"
                    android:id="@+id/shaparak_img"
                    android:layout_weight="2"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/receipt_balance"
                android:id="@+id/trx_type"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@id/headerReceiptLayout"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/receiptLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/postal_code_tv"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:layout_weight="5"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/postal_code_txt"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:id="@+id/postal_code_label" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec13"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status"
                    >
                </View>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/contact_number_tv"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:layout_weight="5"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/contact_number_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/contact_number_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec1"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status"
                    >
                </View>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/merchant_name_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/merchant_name_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/merchant_name_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec12"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/terminal_id_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/terminal_number_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/terminal_id_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec5"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status" >
                </View>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/card_number_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/card_number_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/card_number_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec6"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status">
                </View>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/payment_type_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/type_payment_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/payment_type_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec7"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status" >
                </View>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/trace_number_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/trace_number_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/trace_number_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec8"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status" >
                </View>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/date_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/payment_date"
                        android:id="@+id/date_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec9"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status">
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/RRN_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/RRN_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/RRN_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec4"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status" >
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/payment_result_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/payment_result_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/payment_result_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec11"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status" >
                </View>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/shenase_qabzLayout"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:visibility="gone">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/shenase_qabz_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/bill_id_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/shenase_qabz_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/shenase_pardakhtLayout"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:id="@+id/shenase_pardakht_tv"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="left"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/payment_id_txt"
                        android:id="@+id/shenase_pardakht_label"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="right"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/line_rec10"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/connection_status" >
                </View>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/amount_recepit_tv"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/fail_opration_guide_tv"
                    android:text="@string/fail_opration_guide_txt"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="@string/screen_shot_txt"
        android:id="@+id/screen_shot_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:background="@color/blue_10"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="@string/confrim_txt"
        android:id="@+id/receipt_conf_btn"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:background="@color/blue_10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: buttons icons are also place wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use gravity "start" and "end" instead of "right" and "left" and then simple apply the page rtl option

Answer (score 0):

when you set `"right"` attribute to your gravity use `"end"` too
and when set `"left"` use `"start"` too

like this:

```
android:gravity="right"
android:gravity="end"
```

if this didn't work let me know.
i have a custom method for Persian language.